# Progress Bar delay

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day!

I created a progress bar that has a timer. My problem is how to improve this, because there is a one second delay when I click the pause button and resume button. Also, when the progress bar starts, it will not start at 1% width. I would also like to fix the deduction timer. When the user clicks the wrong answer, it will automatically deduct by two seconds.

But my biggest problem is the delay for pause and resume. Thank you!
[jsfiddle.net/progressBar](https://jsfiddle.net/t5k2ys1e/1/)

```js
const progressBarTimer = document.getElementById("progress-bar-time");
const wrongButton = document.getElementById("wrongbtn");
const wrongLabel = document.getElementById('wrong-label');

const gameplayTime = 30;
const oneSecondSpeed = 1000;

let interval;
let gameSeconds = 0;
let timerValue;

wrongButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  wrongLabel.innerHTML = ' Wrong';
});


window.onload = startGamePlay();

function startGamePlay() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = setInterval(gamePlayStart, oneSecondSpeed); // 1 second interval <- causes of delayed
  function gamePlayStart() {
    if (gameSeconds >= gameplayTime) {
      gameSeconds = 1;
      clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
      gameSeconds++;

      let labelWrong = wrongLabel.innerHTML;
      if (labelWrong === " Wrong") {
        gameSeconds += 2;
        wrongLabel.innerHTML = " No";
      }

      timerValue = Math.floor((gameSeconds / gameplayTime) * 100);
      progressBarTimer.style.width = `${timerValue}%`;
    }
  }
}



function setIntervalStop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}

let playerPauseTheGame = true;
const pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause");

pauseButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (playerPauseTheGame == true) {
    setIntervalStop();

    pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Resume';

    wrongButton.disabled = true;
    playerPauseTheGame = false;
  } else {
    startGamePlay();

    pauseButton.innerHTML = 'Pause';

    wrongButton.disabled = false;
    playerPauseTheGame = true;
  }
});
```

```css
#myProgress {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 28px;
  background: #e49076;
}

#progress-bar-time {
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  float: right;
  background: #086788;
  height: 28px;
  transition: width 1s linear;
}

button {
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

#wrong-label {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="progress-bar-time"></div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="pause">Pause</button>
<button type="button" id="wrongbtn">Wrong Answer</button><span id='wrong-label'> No</span>
```

Comment: Have you solved this? How have you approached the issue?